# What is running my WCF Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, service

I'm getting an error when I try to run my WCF Service on IIS instead of ASP.NET Development Server.

**Clarification:** I don't get an error when I run the WCF Service when using a Windows Service or ASP.NET Development Server. **ONLY IIS is the problem.**

I'm using a console app to test the service. I've never had problems with the service until i tried using the IIS port.

Here is my app.config file of the console app. The top address and port number is the ASP.NET Dev Server port.  The second one is the IIS port.

The following is my App.config file. The top one IIS port. The active one is the ASP.NET Development Server port. When I run the ASP.NET port, I get no errors. When I run the IIS port, I get an error. (Also I have about 4 ASP.NET ports appearing on my Taskbar. I don't know why.)

My App.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
<!-- <endpoint address="http://localhost:9876/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"-->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:5182/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"       
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWebService" 
contract="MyWCF_ServiceReference.IWebService"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here are some  images.

This is the error message that I'm getting.

[image: Error Message]

Is there a reason why the address below is different from the previous ones?
http:// localhost:8732 /Design_Time_Addresses/WCFServiceLibrary/WebService/mex

[image: Different Address]

This is where it is crashing for some unknown reason. Its worth noting that part of the service works. Its only when it get to ValidPerson that it crashes.

**(This also doesn't happen when using the ASP.NET Development Server port 5182. Only when using IIS port 9876)**

[image]

This shows that at the WCF Service itself, the ValidPerson is actually working.

[image]

Here is the conf file its running on.

[image]

I hope you guys can help me. It must be something simple.

Comment: Restart you machine/IIS and try.. It may possible of cache.

Comment: This did not work. For some reason at port 9876, it crashes but not at the port of 5182 (the ASP.NET Development Server).

Comment: I think I know the problem. After realizing that it works with my Windows Service, a friend called and i was talking to him and told him, it partially works with IIS. Its only when it gets to the database that is crashes!  He said it must be a permissions issue. When i first did this, i was concerned about the application pool permissions, but i assumed it was ok because I was using the same app pool. That was on a different freaking server and a different database! So that's probably the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i wasn't asking the right question although i was learning as I went.

I need to make sure the address in the config file matched either the ASP.NET development server's address (which is mostly likely the default) or change it to the IIS address which would require me to check where the WSDL was being hosted adn use that address instead of the default one. Or use the addrress assigned to my Windows Service which i could find by opening up the project file and seeing which number and address was assigned to it.

The real problem was that my Application Pool account in SQL Server needed to be set to a role of db_owner. Then all my problems went away (once i got it on the right ports with the right addresses.)